# Flask appending HTML to a static served file

Tags: python, html, flask

Hopefully this will be an easy question for someone with more experience in Flask than me. I'm serving a static file, and I just want to append some HTML to it, or have the file served below some text. Is there any way to do this or am I approaching it the wrong way?

```
@app.route('/compile/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return *(Random HTML here)* + send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

Everything I try creates an error and I can't find anything else dealing with this problem. I thought about maybe printing the file from an HTML template but it gave me an error when I try to upload the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `send_from_directory()` is a function that calls a system function to deliver the file directly from disk. It does not simply return the file content.

Comment: Is there a way to return the file content without using send_from_directory then?

Comment: Can you share your error log and explain the code you're trying to implement a little bit more detailed?

Comment: There are several ways to achieve the goal. One possibility would be to use ```send_file``` in combination with ```StringIO``` or ```BytesIO```, but a streamed response using a generator would also be possible. There are probably more suitable solutions. Please describe more details.

Comment: The error log comes from using send_from_directory as a string when it's actually a response variable (which I think is unique to Flask)

Comment: I'm not sure what other details you're looking for. Basically, this prints out a file onto a webpage. I just want to be able to add other text to the webpage as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be reduced to

```
@route('/compile/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    html_prefix = ...
    html_suffix = ...
    return html_prefix + content(filename) + html_suffix
```

where the an easy way to get the content is

```
def content(filename)
    with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Error handling is left an an exercise. If you need to change the mimetype of the response (or the status code to something other than 200), see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses

Comment: Thanks! this is more or less what I was looking for. Although now the file formatting looks weird, it's not doing newlines correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for could be an [`iFrame`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) in combination with `send_from_directory`. It is versatile, easy to use and would make the most sense to me.

```
@app.route('/compile/<path:filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

@app.route('/compile/')
def compile():
    return render_template('compile.html')
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Compile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      src="{{ url_for('uploaded_file', filename='example.txt') }}"
      style="border: 1px solid black; width:100%;"
      ></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```